# Header won't work with conditions

Tags: php, redirect, if-statement

I have been trying to get a page working for a number of days now, and there doesn't seem to be much help from the "related" questions on this site.

I have made a signup.php page, which has a form for inputting user credentials to signup up for the site I am building, when the form is filled out and the user presses the 'submit' button, the form uses the action "signupsuccess.php" which has all of the php code for inserting the credentials into the database, and then redirects the user to the "Login.php" page.

**My problem:**
I have written code to say that if the user has not put in any data for one of the fields in the form, then they are brought back to the signup.php page by using this code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['fname'])&&($_POST['lname'])&&($_POST['email'])&&($_POST['pass'])){
    header('Location:Signup.php');
    exit;
}
else{
$host = "localhost";
$user = "******";
$password = "******";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$db = mysql_select_db('*****', $conn);
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $fname = addslashes ($_POST['fname']);
   $lname = addslashes ($_POST['lname']);
   $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
   $pass = addslashes($_POST['pass']);
}
else
{
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $pass= $_POST['pass'];
}
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where pass='$pass' AND email='$email'", $conn);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
    $errors[] = 'That user already exists, try another email';
}else
{

$sql = "INSERT INTO users ".
       "(fname,lname, pass, email) ".
       "VALUES('$fname','$lname','$pass','$email')";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
}
}
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

But the header() just won't bring the user back when they haven't put anything in to the fields. Is there anything I am doing obviously wrong or can anyone help me sort out the redirection of the user if they haven't entered anything.

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['fname'])&&($_POST['lname'])&&($_POST['email'])&&($_POST['pass']))` it should probably say | | instead of &&. And you also need to call isset on all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. If you're just trying to check to see if those variables are set you need to call `isset()` on all of them.

You can do this with individual calls to `isset()` or all in one call.

```
if(!isset($_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['pass'])){
    header('Location:Signup.php');
    exit;
}
```

FYI, you are *wide open* to SQL injections. `addslashes()` does **not** prevent SQL injections. Also, the `mysql_*` funcstions are obsolete and you should not be writing new code using them. Look into mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah I've been looking at PDO, and it just looked a bit alien to me, just starting out on PHP. I'll keep the security in mind too!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need a redirection, you probably should overcome this issue from the frontend, maybe a js validation could do the trick and is way simpler.

1.- change the action of submit to run the function "validate()"

2.- create the function that will be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function validate(){
    if ($.trim($("#inputid").val()) == ""){
         $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
    } else if ($.trim($("#inputid2").val()) == "") {
         $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
    } else if ($.trim($("#inputid3").val()) == "") {
         $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
    } else {
         submit();
    }   
}

});
```

Where '#input?' is the selector for the input you want to validate and null is the value that you want to avoid, in this case, no value, just empty input. Then if all the inputs are filled it will execute submit() function which you should create to do whatever he has to.

Note: This kind of selectors are for jquery so you must include it in your code as well, put this in your header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Note 2: This is the frontend approach. I don't know if this is convenient but at least is an option and helps.

Good luck!

Comment: I was going to use the echo  `<script>window.location("Signup.php");</script>`, but I wasn't sure if it would work!

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement was the problem. because the isset was only affecting

```
$_POST['fname'],
```

the if statment was being skipped so

```
header('Location:Signup.php')
```

was not being reached.

I like to put

```
echo 'test';
```

in my code while i am testing it and move it around the code. That way, if it is not echoing 'test', i know that the code isn't even being reached. That could have helped you in this case, showing you that the problem wasn't the header, it was the if statement. Also, consider using PDO for mysql connections. It is more secure against mysql injections.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition (if corrected according to the previous answers) would still always result in the `else` case. 
Since you are checking for `$_POST` fields, those will always be present.
 `isset()`returns false if the variable is not set (but it is: it comes from your form) or is NULL (which it is not: it contains an empty value). So, isset() will return true fopr every field. 
What you need is, for each field: 
`if (empty(trim($_POST['fname']))) || ... )`
`empty()` returns false when the variable is not set or empty (i.e NULL, an empty string, 0, 0.0, false, etc, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
Plus, you need to do something about the deprecated mysql_functions and your vulnerability to attacks.